# How to attach Particle system to 'bottom' of node

Tags: swift, scenekit, swift-playground

I'm trying to get  flame particle system to appear from a nozzle but instead of it appearing at the bottom of the nozzle the particles appear from the top making it look like the nozzle is on fire. Particle systems do have a Position property according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem/particleproperty/1524136-position) but I can't seem to use `flameParticle.position`

Comment: Just add a child node and let the particles emit from that.

Comment: It was off position when testing on Playgrounds on the Mac but looked fine on my iPad, so just left it at that @Dominic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particle system was off position when testing on Playgrounds on the Mac but it’s fine on my iPad.